# How to define a raster in ArcGIS Pro for use in the Raster Calc. tool with Python script

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, spatial-analyst, raster-calculator

As part of a lab for an intro GIS course, I'm trying to create a new elevation layer from an existing elevation raster, to create a raster layer that only displays where the elevation is above 224 meters.  The directions send me to the 'Raster Calculator' tool and instruct to insert the layer into the code box like so: existing_rasterlayer < 224 .
When I attempt to run it, the tool says it cannot, b/c existing_rasterlayer is not defined.  My roommate suggested it needs to be projected. I assigned the layer a projection, and yet the 'Raster Calc' tool says the layer remains undefined.

How would I go about defining it?

Here is a pic of the received error and tool I used.

[image]

Comment: (...perhaps it's not Python script, but it looks similar)

Comment: Place your raster layer within double quote like:  "this" < 224

Comment: Anytime you "[assign] the layer a projection" it's likely you have corrupted the dataset.  This is 99.99999% true when your dataset "needs to be projected", because at this point in the life of spatial data, pretty much **all data has a defined projection**.  Redefining the projection is almost always going to introduce new problems.  If you set a goal of ***projecting***  your data instead of "assigning"  a projection, you are more likely to make forward progress.

Answer (score 0):

Two ways:

1. Ensure the raster name is in "double quotes"

`"elev_elev_ProjectRaster2" < 224`

2. Double-click the raster name in the rasters list (which will add the quotes automatically)

[image]